# ActionListener - Tracing if actionPerformed is called inside actionPerformed method?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, actionlistener

Say I have a 'Select' JButton with SelectPieceListener.
I want to check if the action(clicking Select Button) is performed again or not.
However, actionPerformed is void, so I cannot use it as boolean expression.

Is there any way to do that?
Or is it better to use another JButton to handle this?

Thank you.

```
public class SelectPieceListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(c == _st.checkMoveImpossible()) {
            System.out.println("No possible move for "+nextPlayer+": click select to skip turn, " +
                    "or click right to move " + t + " pieces.");

            if(**the action is performed**){_board.setcmi(1);}
            _board.update();
        }
```

Comment: Can you clarify a little more?  Do you want to prevent them `actionListener` from been triggered more then once or know if something triggered it again while it was executing?

Comment: Why not simply have a counter variable in the ActionListener class and increment it in the actionPerformed method? I'm not sure if I'm over-simplifying your problem or not, so if this doesn't solve it, please clarify it, greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know if the select button has been clicked once already (1) ? Or do you want to make sure the actionPerformed method isn't called recursively (2)?

(1) Simply add a boolean field to SelectPieceListener called 'selectPressed' (or whatever), and set it to true when actionPerformed is called.

(2) No worries, you don't seem to call it manually.